# Auto set custom metadata based on payment method for WooCommerce orders

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, metadata, orders

I added a select field to WooCommerce admin order pages to order details section using:

```php
add_action('woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_order_details', 'display_option');
function display_option( $order) {
    echo '<div class="options_group">';
    woocommerce_wp_select( array(
        'id'          => '_option',
        'label'       => __( 'Statusas', 'woocommerce' ),
        'desc_tip'    => false,
        'options'     => array(
            ''        => __( 'Pasirinkti statusa', 'woocommerce' ),
            'Apmoketa'    => __('Apmoketa', 'woocommerce' ),
            'Neapmoketa' => __('Neapmoketa', 'woocommerce' ),
        )
    ) );

    echo '</div>';
}
```

and I save the selected value with:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_process_shop_order_meta', 'save_option' );
function save_option( $post_id ){
    $posted_field_value = $_POST['_option'];
    if( ! empty( $posted_field_value ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_option', esc_attr( $posted_field_value ) );
        }
}
```

Now I would like to auto select the value depending on the payment method:

- if it's "stripe" payment, I want to set 'Apmoketa' as value,
- if it's "bacs" payment, I want to set 'Neapmoketa' as value.

I tried various WooCommerce hooks, but mostly I feel as though I should be looking into:

```
if($order->get_payment_method() == 'stripe')
```

and

```
if($order->get_payment_method() == 'bacs')
```

Nothing worked for now.

Some help would be appreciated.

Comment: According to https://wp-kama.com/plugin/woocommerce/hook/woocommerce_process_shop_order_meta, the `woocommerce_process_shop_order_meta` callback function gets both $order_id and $order passed in as parameters already.

Comment: @CBroe Wrong! it's [`do_action( 'woocommerce_process_shop_order_meta', $post_id, $post );`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/release/8.2/plugins/woocommerce/includes/admin/class-wc-admin-meta-boxes.php#L263) since WooCommerce version 2.1…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should use more explicit meta keys instead of `_option` that is confusing and could be used by WordPress / WooCommerce or a 3rd party plugin. Same thing when naming your functions…

Also, as WordPress Posts and Custom Post types already have a status property, you should define a more explicit label name.

I have revised all your code and added a function to auto select that "payment status" based on the payment method:

```php
// Display payment status select field
add_action('woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_order_details', 'admin_order_display_payment_status_select');
function admin_order_display_payment_status_select( $order ) {

    woocommerce_wp_select( array(
        'id'          => '_payment_status',
        'label'       => __( 'Mokėjimo statusas', 'woocommerce' ),
        'desc_tip'    => false,
        'options'     => array(
            ''            => __( 'Pasirinkti mokėjimo statusas', 'woocommerce' ),
            'Apmoketa'    => __('Apmoketa', 'woocommerce' ),
            'Neapmoketa'  => __('Neapmoketa', 'woocommerce' ),
        ),
        'wrapper_class'   => 'form-field-wide',
    ) );
}

// Save selected payment status
add_action( 'woocommerce_process_shop_order_meta', 'admin_order_payment_status_save', 20 );
function admin_order_payment_status_save( $order_id ){
    if( isset($_POST['_payment_status']) && ! empty($_POST['_payment_status']) ) {
        $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
        $order->update_meta_data('_payment_status',  esc_attr($_POST['_payment_status']) );
        $order->save();
    }
}

// Auto select payment status based on payment method
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_changed', 'auto_select_admin_order_payment_status', 10, 4 );
function auto_select_admin_order_payment_status( $order_id, $from_status, $to_status, $order ) {
    if ( $order->get_meta('_payment_status') ) return;

    $order->update_meta_data('_payment_status', $order->get_payment_method() === 'bacs' ? 'Neapmoketa' : 'Apmoketa' );
    $order->save();
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). Tested and works.